# passing param to class with getter and setter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a class with getter and setter methods and I am passing values to the object of that class without calling the setter methods.

But I cant pass any parameters without constructor.

It's working when I use a constructor.

```
//
@Entity
public class player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Player_Id")
    private  String id;
    @Column(name = "PlayerName")
    private String PlayerName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return PlayerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String PlayerName) {
        this.PlayerName = PlayerName;
    }
}

@Service
public class playerservice {

    @Autowired
    List<player> list ;

    public playerservice(){
        list.add(new player("1","vijay"));//not able to pass parameters
    }
}
```

I am not able create object by passing values

Comment: The call `new Something(x,y)` calls the constructor of `Something` that accepts two parameters with the given type. Of course, if you don't have such a constructor, you can't make that call.

Comment: Are you telling us, that you can't call a parameterized constructor if you not have such a constructor? That's Java (and any other language will behave the same).

Comment: did not understand your problem. Please explain. What do you want to pass? why you are not happy with constructors? why you are not writing proper constructor in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not happy with this constructor?

```
public player(String player_id, String player_name){
    this.player_id = player_id;
    this.name = player_name
}
```

Constructs are the way to inform your class how to instantiate objects. The class needs to know explicitly the data types you are passing using these constructors. You can create more than one constructor on your convenience.  However, if you did not write any constructor, there is a default constructor that comes with each class but did not pass any values for you.

Comment: i know it works whin i write a constructor, but it should even  work with just a getter setter right?

Comment: yeah, but you need to say: 
`list.get(0).setPlayerName("the name you want")`

Comment: you need to call the method in order to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use Spring Dependency Injection (i.e. wiring) in a way that it is not designed to be used.  Spring won't and can't inject parameters into the object constructed in your code using `new`.

If you want to use Spring wiring dynamically, you need to do something along the lines of this blog:

- ["How to create Spring beans dynamically"](https://gopinathb4u.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/create-dynamic-spring-beans/)

As you can see, there are a few lines of code set everything up.  And once you have set up the context, you say to Spring "make me a bean", and it does a whole bunch of reflective magic to construct the bean, and pass it the arguments that will be wired into it.  It will probably 2 to 3 orders of magnitude slower than the simple Java solution of using `new` and passing parameters.